# Math.acos showing worng result

Tags: java, android-studio, math

I have this code:

```
double elev0 = Math.cos(Math.toRadians((40.664)))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians((17.031)));

double elev4 = Math.acos(Math.toRadians(elev0));
```

But when i print the elev4 variable it isn´t the correct answer. It should say 43.507 and it says 1.55

Comment: don't convert to radians second time, `elev0` is not angle at all

Comment: i made that and the answer is 0.75 not 43

Comment: If you want the result (elev4) to be in degrees you have to convert it into degrees: `double elev4 = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(elev0));`

Comment: thank you i know see my error thank you